# Is 'ORDER BY _id' enough to get rows in insertion order?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm using SQLite DB in my Android app.
Now I need to implement data extraction in the same order in which it was inserted.
Is it enough to do `SELECT ... ORDER BY _id ...` if the `_id` column is `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`?
Or should I add a column to store the date and time a row has been created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ORDER BY _id`.  Make sure you are using a List and not a Set....

Answer (score 1):

No need, an id generated by AUTOINCREMENT is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you just need the order, you may use such statement or just simple "SELECT ... FROM sometable". Results will be equals.